# Using java.util.Stack.iterator to display contents the stack

Tags: java, iterator, stack

In the code below I pushed 1,5,3 into the stack respectively means the top 3 is located at the top of stack and 1 at the bottom( which is the case) however when i use iterator to display the contents of the stack, the iterator apparently treats stack like queue and

instead of displaying

3<-5<-1<-Bottom!

it outputs:

1<-5<-3<-Bottom!

why does the iterator do this?

If that's natural behavior of iterator then how can i display the contents of a Stack without using pop?

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Stack;

public class MyStack{

    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();

    public void display(){
                Iterator <Integer> it = stack.iterator();
                while(it.hasNext()){
                    System.out.print(it.next()+"<-");
                }
        System.out.println("Bottom!");
    }


    void pushAll(int [] data){
        for(int i:data){
            stack.push(i);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String [] org){
        MyStack stak= new MyStack();
        stak.pushAll(new int [] {1,5,3});
        stak.display();
    } 


}
```

Console:

```
1<-5<-3<-Bottom!
```

while it should output:

```
3<-5<-1<-Bottom!
```

Comment: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4475301. And why don't you want to use `pop()` ?

Comment: @ZouZou cuz pop will empty my stack. Say for debugging purposes you wanna see the contents of stack at any time. If I use pop then again have to push them back to keep the stack unchanged

Comment: You ... don't. The iterator only goes one way (specifically, the same way as in `Vector` which is where it comes from). Which is one of the reasons the javadoc recommends not using the `Stack` class anymore.

Comment: If `Stack` isn't used, then which class is used instead or did you mean not to use `Iterator` for `Stack`?

Answer (score 2):

The hacky way would be to use a `listIterator` and start it from the end :

```
ListIterator<Integer> it = stack.listIterator(stack.size());
while(it.hasPrevious()){
    System.out.print(it.previous()+"<-");
}
System.out.println("Bottom!");
```

Answer (score 2):

You ... don't. The iterator only goes one way (specifically, the same way as in `Vector` which is where it comes from since `Stack` is a subclass of `Vector`).

Technically you can get around this with the `ListIterator` but really this is one of the reasons the javadoc recommends not using the `Stack` class anymore.

Use a class with the `Deque` interface (such as an [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html)) as recommended and you then have the `descendingIterator()` call.

```
Iterator<Integer> it = arrayDeque.descendingIterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    System.out.print(it.next()+"<-");
}
```